# ANDROID: call many Activity from another Activity

Tags: android

I try to call 2 Activities from the main Activity. however, the first Activity didn't work, just the second worked correctly. But when I just called one Activity, it run well. So i think the problem is that I can't call 2 Activities at the same time:

this is my code
the main Activity:

[CODE]

```
package com.example.Test2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import at.abraxas.amarino.Amarino;

import com.example.Test2.subclass;;

public class Test2Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final String DEVICE_ADDRESS = "00:06:66:43:9B:56";

        Amarino.connect(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS);

        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, subclass.class);
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, subclass1.class);
        startActivity(i2);
        startActivity(i1);

    }
}
```

The subclass:

[CODE]

```
package com.example.Test2;

public class subclass extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

    // subclass code
}
```

[/CODE]

the subclass1

[CODE]

```
package com.example.Test2;

public class subclass1 extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{

    // subclass1 code
}
```

[/CODE]

I also declare 2 Activities: subclass and subclass1 in manifest file

thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 3):

> So i think the problem is that I can't call 2 Activities at the same
>   time

Correct. And you have only one screen on your device.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, i just have one on screen. exactly, I'm trying to transmit the signal to Arduino board, the subclass is used to handle two toggle buttons and the subclass1 is used to handle a seekbar

Comment: Ok, in that case, use single Activity and have the two toggle buttons and also the seekbar on that. They still use different event handlers and you can send different data to your Arduino when user interacts with them. I.e. combine the functional codes of your two Activities into one.

Comment: I tried it but subclass implements OnCheckedChangeListener and the subclass1 implements OnSeekBarChangeListener, so how i combine them. i really confuse about this.

Comment: The listeners are *interfaces*. So, a subclass can implement multiple listeners without any issues. `class MySubClass implements OnCheckedChangeListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener`. You might be confused interface implementation with subclassing. A Java class can inherit only one class but can implement more than one interface.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Implementing_an_interface

Comment: thank you very much. Your suggestions really help me so much :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't start two activities at the same time.

If you want to put those 2 activities to the task stack in the specified order you should make the subclass activity start the subclass1 activity early (in onCreate for example).